# [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory php

Tags: php, database-connection

I get the following error when I go to http://zyz.com/abc/index.php:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xyz.com\httpdocs\abc\classes/mysqli.cls.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xyz.com\httpdocs\abc\classes\_ClassLoader.inc on line 5
```

below is the class loader.inc file

```
    <?php

function __autoload($clsname) {
    $ClassDir = dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/";
    require_once $ClassDir . strtolower( $clsname ) . '.cls.inc';
}

?>
```

Comment: +1 Because that's not a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have `mysqli` installed, but are trying to use it. Your `__autoload` function tries to load it from the directory of the web application, but that's not where it would be located  if it was installed. [Install and configure `mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) to fix the problem. You can check whether it is installed by writing `phpinfo();` in any `.php` file.

Comment: I think thats the problem. when i opened the php.ini file there is nothing like ";extension=php_mysqli.dll" which obviously means(to my knowledge) mysqli is not insatlled

Answer (score 0):

Do you have file mysqli.cls.inc at C:\Inetpub\vhosts\xyz.com\httpdocs\abc\classes folder? Check exact name